Scheduled task fails while Manually running the same function works in Laravel
I have a script that connects to multiple servers and returns stock on hand at each server. My system is run on Debian with its own postgres DB and I am requesting information from MSSQL databases.
Below is my helper function that allows me to call from Kernel.php (Scheduled) and from a controller (Manual). When I call it manually everything works fine. Through the sheduled task set to run every 15 min I get a PDOException: could not find driver in ...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:65.
Everything was working well until I ran composer update updating Laravel from v10.13.5 to v10.48.9 in an effort to get a package to work.
function auto_update_branch_stocks()
{
    $branches = Branch::orderBy('branch_code', 'asc')->where('active', "1")->get();
    $servers = '';

    foreach ($branches as $branch) {
        DB::purge('company_branch');
        Config::set('database.connections.company_branch', [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => '',
            'host' => $branch->host,
            'port' => $branch->port,
            'database' => $branch->database,
            'username' => config('database.connections.dripsvr.username'),
            'password' => config('database.connections.dripsvr.password'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ]);
        
        try {
            $branch_stock = DB::connection('company_branch')
            ->table('dbo.StkItem')
            ->select('dbo.StkItem.Code as item_code', 'dbo.StkItem.Description_1 as item_description', 'dbo.StkItem.StockLink as stock_id', 'dbo._etblStockQtys.WhseID as warehouse_id', 'dbo._etblStockQtys.QtyOnHand as qty', 'dbo._etblStockCosts.AverageCost as avg_cost', 'dbo._etblStockCosts.LatestCost as last_cost', 'dbo._etblPriceListPrices.fExclPrice as sp_excl', 'dbo._etblStockDetails.GroupID as group_id', 'dbo.GrpTbl.StGroup as group', 'dbo.GrpTbl.Description as group_description')
            ->leftJoin('dbo._etblStockQtys', 'dbo.StkItem.StockLink', '=', 'dbo._etblStockQtys.StockID')
            ->leftJoin('dbo._etblStockCosts', 'dbo.StkItem.StockLink', '=', 'dbo._etblStockCosts.StockID')
            ->leftJoin('dbo._etblPriceListPrices', 'dbo.StkItem.StockLink', '=', 'dbo._etblPriceListPrices.iStockID')
            ->leftJoin('dbo._etblStockDetails', 'dbo.StkItem.StockLink', '=', 'dbo._etblStockDetails.StockID')
            ->leftJoin('dbo.GrpTbl', 'dbo._etblStockDetails.GroupID', '=', 'dbo.GrpTbl.idGrpTbl')
            ->where('dbo._etblStockQtys.WhseID', '=', $branch->warehouse_id)
            ->where('dbo._etblStockCosts.WhseID', '=', $branch->warehouse_id)
            ->where('dbo._etblPriceListPrices.iWarehouseID', '=', 1)
            ->where('dbo._etblPriceListPrices.iPriceListNameID', '=', 1)
            ->where('dbo._etblStockDetails.WhseID', '=', $branch->warehouse_id)
            ->get()->map(function($stock, $key) {
                return [
                    'item_code' => (string)$stock->item_code,
                    'item_description' => (string)$stock->item_description,
                    'stock_id' => (int)$stock->stock_id,
                    'warehouse_id' => (int)$stock->warehouse_id,
                    'qty' => (int)$stock->qty,
                    'avg_cost' => $stock->avg_cost,
                    'last_cost' => $stock->last_cost,
                    'sp_excl' => $stock->sp_excl,
                    'group_id' => (int)$stock->group_id,
                    'group' => (string)$stock->group,
                    'group_description' => (string)$stock->group_description
                ];
            })->all();
            Stock::where('warehouse_id', $branch->warehouse_id)->delete();
            Stock::insert($branch_stock);
        } 
        
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::info('Error for ' . $branch->name . ', ' . $e);
            $servers = $servers . ', ' . $branch->name;
        }

    }
}

Feel free to critique my code, always happy to improve. but i do not think the error is in this snippet, it has to be somewhere else.

Does the scheduled task run with the same PHP version as the web app?

Maybe, you are missing sqlsrv driver. let check with php.ini

@Mai Truong, If I am missing the driver how does it work when I run this manually from a controller?

@Olivier how would they run in 2 different php versions?

If you have 2 different versions of PHP installed on the server, the cron job may use one, and the web server the other one.

Ok I have php 8.1, 8.2 and 8.3 on my environment. In my composer.json I "require: { "php": "8.1 || ^8.3.5".... Can I just add 8.2 in there as well?

You should edit the cron job to use the same PHP version as your web server.

This is sounding promising, where can I do this? My cron job looks like this * * * * * cd /var/www/html/driptech && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

You can use the absolute path to the correct php binary. Or make php (which I guess is a symlink) point to the correct version.

I've tried to rewrite the cron job to use a specific php but I am getting the same error.  * * * * * /usr/bin/php8.2 cd /var/www/html/driptech && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

The correct command is cd /var/www/html/driptech && /usr/bin/php8.2 artisan schedule:run.

You are the GOAT!! Do you want to answer properly and I will give you the credit

The web server and the cron job don't run the same version of PHP, which explains why the former has the correct extensions enabled in php.ini, and not the latter.
To run the job with the correct PHP version, you can modify the command to use the absolute path to the php binary:
cd /var/www/html/driptech && /usr/bin/php8.2 artisan schedule:run


This worked like a charm. The Laravel documentation has >> /dev/null 2>&1 at the end of their cron script, is it necessary for me to include?

@nj167252 It's used to redirect output, it may not be necessary, but won't harm to put it.
